# Bitcoin ABC stucked on connect to peer

Tags: block, bitcoin-cash, testnet, peers

So i have a testnet bitcoin cash that i just put txindex=1 (because a api requires this) and it stuck on block 1155875 and I restart the core and even follow the step in this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/6r64gx/bitcoin_abc_client_sync_stuck_at_478558/

and still not helps and even add a additional peer and modify my firewall.

so is there anyway i can fix this?

Comment: I had this same problem initially, but invalidate/reconsider fixed it for me.  Maybe you could post the contents of your debug.log file?

Comment: Ok ,I did restart the core after running the commands on the link above because it was stucked on syncing header at 100% for a while and the

Logs: [log link](https://pastebin.com/raw/Kki3fzVh)

Comment: That log doesn't seem to show where you get to block 1155875.

Comment: Hmm... but I just ran the core right now and it still saying connecting to peer and stucked on that block and i can upload a gif to show u if you need it

Comment: I just invalidateblock and reconsiderblock again and let it sync for few minutes and see if it helps